# RewriteRule or 301 redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I have inherited a website from my friend which was done in ColdFusion. All urls are like:
`index.cfm`, `filename.cfm?xid=MN`

I did simple rules like this:

```
RewriteRule filename.cfm filename.php
```

and it did the work for top level files.

But now I'm working on second level files and they have links like this: `filename.cfm?id=wanted&xid=MN` wich suppose to open another page, the problem is when I write this:

```
RewriteRule filename.cfm?id=wanted&xid=MN folder/filename.php
```

it doesn't work. I know it's a stupid question for a savvy developer, but I'm a newbie and I need help. Please suggest a solution. This is very much appreciated.

```
The pattern of those urls:
I have                                 I need
/fileone.cfm?id=overview&xid=MN        /folderone/overview.php
/fileone.cfm?id=wanted&xid=MN          /folderone/wanted.php
/fileone.cfm?id=services&xid=MN        /folderone/services.php


/filetwo.cfm?id=overview&xid=MN        /folderwto/overview.php
/filetwo.cfm?id=wanted&xid=MN          /folderwto/wanted.php
/filetwo.cfm?id=services&xid=MN        /folderwto/services.php
```

And so on....

Comment: I'm not sure why you are interested in making Cold Fusion look like PHP, can you elaborate?

Comment: there a lot of inboint links to ColdFusion pages

Comment: _`RewriteRule filename.cfm filename.php`
and it did the work for top level files._ What do you mean it works? you are directing `.cfm` to `.php` files!

Comment: Ok, I want that when visitor requests file.cfm my file.php would be shown, this is what rewrite does, doesn't it?

Comment: I have problems with long strings.
If I put something like that:

Comment: 301 redirect /filetwo.cfm?id=overview&xid=MN /folder/overview.php
it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /file(one|two)\.cfm\?id=([^&]+)&xid=MN [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ /folder%1/%2.php? [L]
```

This will work for all of the rewrites you requested above e.g. when the user asks for `/fileone.cfm?id=overview&xid=MN`, they will get `/folderone/overview.php`.

If you want to 301 redirect the users change the last rule to

```
RewriteRule ^ /folder%1/%2.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for solution! It does redirect but it changes URL as well and I loose PR :((

Comment: is there a way to save the look of the URL /filetwo.cfm?id=overview&xid=MN but to show another file from a directory?

Comment: @AntonPotapenko If you leave out the `R` i.e. just `[L]`, it should not redirect. If you use the `[L,R=301]` it will redirect and you will temporarily loose PR, but it will be transferred over to the new URLs after a while.

Comment: For some reasons it works with R=301 and does not work without it :(